# How do I insert a custom object?

Tags: apex, custom-object

I have a custom object called `Visitor` with two custom fields, `Name` and `Identifier`. I am trying to add a record with this piece of controller code:

```
 public String getResponse() {
        System.debug('I am in!');

        if(validate()) {
            Visitor newVisitor = new Visitor();
            newVisitor.Name = 'John Smith';
            newVisitor.Identifier = 'john@somewhere.com';
            insert newVisitor;
            return '{"success":"true"}';
        }

        return '{"success":"false"}';
    }
```

When I try to save my code, I get this error:

> Compile Error: Invalid type: Visitor at line 13 column 38

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: people here are always gentle and very helpful. :) If you are satisfied with the answer given pls accept it. Welcome to APEX..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Visitor` should be `Visitor__c`.  All custom objects are suffixed with `__c`, as should all of your custom fields on either standard or custom objects.  So, your code would look something like this:

```
Visitor__c newVisitor = new Visitor__c ();
newVisitor.Name = 'John Smith';
newVisitor.Identifier__c = 'john@somewhere.com';
insert newVisitor;
```

Only standard fields are not suffixed with `__c`, e.g. `Name`, `Id`, `CreatedDate` etc.

**EDIT**: boots and braces with Try/Catch

See the docs for a full description of the Insert operation:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_insert.htm

Doing a DML insert/update/upsert could result in an exception depending on a number of factors:

- It could be that the operation will mean that you exceed a Governor limit (see
  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm).
  If you are inserting multiple records, 'bulkification' will most 
  likely be required to prevent this.
- It could also (and more likely) be caused by an issue with the record
  that you are trying to insert (e.g. missing required field, failed validation etc.).

Surrounding your operation with a Try/Catch is always good practice and will allow you to fail gracefully should the worst happen. **Note**, you cannot fail gracefully with a Try/Catch for a Governor limit issue.

There are essentially two ways to Try/Catch for DML statements (sorry, formatting has gone screwy):

This will suffice for a single record (though you could use the second option here too):

```
try
{
    insert newVisitor;
}
catch( DmlException ex )
{
    // fail gracefully
}
```

This may be preferable for multiple records, where the 'false' parameter indicates that this is (not) an 'all or nothing' insert:

```
Database.SaveResult[] MySaveResult = Database.Insert(newVisitors, false);
for (Database.SaveResult sr : MySaveResult) {
    if (!sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Identifier__c too ;) Phil, maybe you can simply post fixed code snippet?

Comment: @eyescream done :)

Comment: Another suggestion I often see overlooked is that passing key value pairs to the sobject constructor actually saves script statements. `new Visitor__c (Name='John Smith', Identifier__c = 'john@somewhere.com')` only uses one script statement, instead of the 3 in your example.

Comment: Very good point @DanielBlackhall

Comment: @PhilHawthorn One more thing just to improve our answers can we have try catch too for insert call.

Comment: Thanks guys! Sounds like @Mohith has a good suggestion. What type of exception can one expect to catch a failed insert.

Comment: `try { } catch(DmlException e) { }`

Comment: Partial operations do not throw any exceptions for failed records...

Comment: Yes, good point - no one else noticed :D. Edited.