# Insert record from custom object

Tags: visualforce, force.com, community, apex, customer-community

I am trying to insert a record on a child object (Idea_Comments__c) of the standard controller object (Idea_Lobby__c). After insertion, I would also like it forward to a VF page. So far, I have not had any success with my page. After clicking submit, the page tries to send me to login.

Here's my extension so far:

```
public with sharing class detExt {

private ApexPages.StandardController theController;
public Idea_Comments__c ideaCom {get; set;}
public Idea_Comments__c setideaCom(Idea_Comments__c op){
this.ideaCom=op;
return ideaCom;
}

public detExt(ApexPages.StandardController acon) {

   theController = acon;
   ideaCom=new Idea_Comments__c();

 }
  public List<Idea_Comments__c> getdetExt()
    {

        ID masterID = theController.getID();

        return [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, Comment__c
        FROM Idea_Comments__c
        WHERE Idea_Lobby__c = :masterID
        order by CreatedDate DESC ];
    }
 public pagereference saveComments(){

Idea_Comments__c cd = new Idea_Comments__c();
cd.Comment__c=ideaCom.Comment__c;
insert cd;
PageReference congratsPage = Page.Congrats_Page;
  congratsPage.setRedirect(true);
  return congratsPage;

}
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

**UPDATE:**
I got it figured out. All I had to do was remove `congratsPage.setRedirect(true);`.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Try to debug `cd` right after `insert` call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I insert a custom object?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/how-do-i-insert-a-custom-object)

Comment: What is the code for your VF page submit button?

Comment: Silly question, but is there actually a page called Congrats_Page in your org?  I've  seen this happen when it doesn't know where to redirect.